# How to give access to users belonged to one Resource Group ,so that they do not find out the service account credentials?

Tags: azure, containers, registry, credentials

I have created an Azure Container Registry ,have Microsoft subscription inherited to the users in that particular Resource Group .How to give access to the users as they can login to the registry using only service principal credentials.What privilege permissions should I give so that they cannot view the credentials in the portal.azure.com and should not push or pull docker images using service principal credentials?

Answer (score 0):

All the roles and permissions for the ACR are shows in the [Azure Container Registry roles and permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles). You can just choose one which you want to use.

The service principal is a little different from the users to do something with appropriate permission. For example, you can use a service principal with only `acrpull` permission to pull the image even the users have the permission to push, but login with the service principal, it just can pull the image.

Comment: I went through that docs, my question is in ACR every one has to pull /push the repo with service account credentials .how to login by other means so that they can push/pull images to ACR without knowing the service account credentials

Comment: @sush As I said, if you use the service principal, then you just can push/pull images and cannot see the credentials in the portal.

Comment: yes that 's a good option though! but was looking for an option such that they do not login through service principal credentials?

Comment: @sush If you do not use the service principal, then you should use the ACR admin user with the credential in Azure portal, but I think the permission is too big.

Comment: .Can I login into ACR by other means without service account cred?

Comment: @sush What do you mean other means? The means except the service principal and the ACR admin user?

Comment: @sush It seems there are no other means to do that.

Comment: yes exactly! Like can they login by their's SSO credentials what they login to portal UI through cmd line so that they push to that particular directory?

Comment: @sush I have no experience with SSO. You can see all the authentications in [Authenticate with a private Docker container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication).

Comment: @sush Maybe you can take a look at [Azure Container Registry integration with Azure Active Directory](https://github.com/Azure/acr/blob/master/docs/AAD-OAuth.md).